# how do i compile this array into a listview in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to programming with Kotlin and hope to get some help with displaying entries in this array to be displayed in a list view
`[Products(id=1, product_name=product_1, qty=13, price=66.00, DEVICE_ID=1, created_at=2019-11-07 11:29:25, updated_at=2019-11-07 16:24:20), Products(id=2, product_name=product_2, qty=12, price=66.00, DEVICE_ID=1, created_at=2019-11-07 11:30:02, updated_at=null)]`

Is there a way to do this? i would like it to be displayed in the same way as this:

[image: Example of the listview]

Comment: Do you have the data in JSON format ? or just like a String as you stated in question?

Comment: You would have to create an adapter, a model and a custom view.

Comment: @Kishita Looks like it is already as objects in an array. That String would be the output of toString on his array of (data) objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/kotlin-recyclerview-example/ as its very easy and simple implementation of a recylerview in kotlin. If you still have an issue then you can share what exact problem/error your are facing.

You can also use this website for json parsing http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/